# Sessions and Authentication

Tags: php, object-oriented, authentication, session

I've a feeling I'm overdoing my `Auth` class, and that it could be done in a simpler and more understandable way.

Could you give me advice on this, please?

This is for my learning process and I just want to learn. This is why I am 'reinventing the wheel'.

```
class Auth
{

    protected $pdo;
    protected $session = null;
    protected $error = array();

    /**
    * 
    */
    function __construct($PDO)
    {
        $this->pdo = $PDO;
    }

    /**
    * 
    */
    public function authenticate_user($password,$email)
    {
        try
        {
            $select_user = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = :email LIMIT 1');
            $select_user->execute(array(':email' => $email));
            $user_data = $select_user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if (password_verify($password,$user_data['user_pass']))
            {
                $this->set_session($user_data);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                $this->error['authenticate_user'] = 'Incorrect email or password';
            }
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    /**
    * 
    */
    public function set_session($user_data)
    {
        if ($user_data)
        {
            $this->session = $user_data;
        }
    }

    /**
    * 
    */
    public function unset_session()
    {
        if (isset($this->session))
        {
            $this->session =  null;
        }
    }

    /**
    * 
    */
    public function get_session()
    {
        if (isset($this->session))
        {
            return $this->session;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
    * 
    */
    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        if (isset($this->session))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
    * 
    */
    public function get_error($key)
    {
        if (isset($this->error[$key]))
        {
            return $this->error[$key];
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

And on the login.php:

```
  if (!empty($_POST))
  {
      $response = $Auth->authenticate_user($_POST['password'],$_POST['email']);
  }

  session_start();

  if (isset($response))
  {
      $_SESSION = $Auth->get_session();
  }

  print_r($_SESSION);

  echo $Auth->get_error('authenticate_user');
```

And in the file that loads all the other files (at the top of everything):

```
if (isset($_SESSION)
{
  $Auth->set_session($_SESSION);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- It seems to me like it would probably make sense for the members of `Auth` to be static, though this may be for some reason undesirable to you. Change it as you see fit.
- Your style contrasts with the industry standard in that you are putting braces on their own lines *for control structures* (i.e. `if`). If this is purely a personal project then it's your choice, but if you're committing this to an existing code base or making it available for public use then it may do you some good to read on a style guide, such as the excellent [PEAR Coding Standards](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php).
- Your database query performs a `SELECT *`. This is, in general, not a good idea. Since you're only using the one column, consider changing it to `SELECT "user_pass"`.
- It doesn't make much sense to me to have a `set_session()` method. Do you really mean to export it as `public`?
- It also doesn't make sense to be saving your SQL row for later retrieval. (Ignore this point if `password_verify()` does something special to the `$user_data` parameter.) This is an `Auth`entication class, not a general `User` class.
- You don't need the `isset()` check in `unset_session()`.

  Aside: You used an inconsistent amount of leading spaces in your question. Ideally, start all code blocks with *exactly* four spaces. I can't tell if your last block really does use only two spaces for indentation (thus diverging from your previous code blocks). If it does, then you should correct it so that your indentation is consistent throughout your project.

Comment: `contrasts with the industry standard in that you are putting braces on their own lines`: how could this be an industry standard? Pretty standard [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html#coding-standard.coding-style.functions-and-methods) and [here (sect. 4.4)](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/)

Comment: @Alex I meant to clarify but I guess I forgot to when I was typing it out. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense :)

Answer (score 4):

The code is understandable, but it can be simplified.

Instead of:

> ```
> public function unset_session()
> {
>     if (isset($this->session))
>     {
>         $this->session =  null;
>     }
> }
> ```

You can simply:

```
public function unset_session()
{
    $this->session =  null;
}
```

---

Instead of:

> ```
> public function get_session()
> {
>     if (isset($this->session))
>     {
>         return $this->session;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         return false;
>     }
> }
> ```

You can simply:

```
public function get_session()
{
    return $this->session;
}
```

(if you don't mind that it returns a falsy value (null) instead of a real false)

---

Instead of:

> ```
> public function is_logged_in()
> {
>     if (isset($this->session))
>     {
>         return true;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         return false;
>     }
> }
> ```

You can simply:

```
public function is_logged_in()
{
    return isset($this->session);
}
```

---

Instead of:

> ```
> public function get_error($key)
> {
>     if (isset($this->error[$key]))
>     {
>         return $this->error[$key];
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         return false;
>     }
> }
> ```

As of PHP 5.3, using the [short ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), you can simply:

```
public function get_error($key)
{
    return $this->error[$key] ?: false;
}
```